# JsonJackson not adding @class

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson, redisson

I am using kotlin with redisson and jsonjackson as the serializer. Previously when I used jackson in java, it would automatically add a '@class' tag to the json so when I came to deserialize it, it would work fine and redisson would know what class to use. Now it no longer does this and when I try to get something out of an RMap<UUID, UserProfile> (UserProfile is an interface", it gives an error which says "jacksonjson missing type id property '@class'" which is obvisouly due to the json missing the '@class' tag.

Anyone know how I can fix this and have jackson automatically add the @class tag like it previously did? Thank you

Comment: ""@class": "net.superiormc.user.UserProfileProvider"" this is the tag I am missing, Jackson used to add this automatically but no longer does.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)` to the implementation class

Comment: Is there any other solution? The annotation can expose the data object

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to annotate classes, it can be configured globally

```
var codec = new org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec(new ObjectMapper()
    .enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, "@class"));

var config = new org.redisson.config.Config()
    .setCodec(codec);
```